# Groupby sum, count, and pattern

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have  a dataframe as shown below

```
   ID Status  Date      Cost
0   1   F   22-Jun-17   500
1   1   M   28-Jul-17   100
2   2   M   29-Jun-17   200
3   3   M   30-Mar-17   300
4   4   F   10-Aug-17   800
5   2   F   2-Sep-17    600
6   2   F   5-Jan-18    500
7   1   F   23-Jun-18   600
8   3   F   20-Jun-18   700
9   1   M   20-Aug-08   150
10  1   F   20-Mar-19   750
11  3   M   11-Feb-19   250
12  4   M   11-Jun-18   100
```

Which is a repair data of mobile.
Where F - Failure, M - Maintenance.
I am new in pandas.
I would like to find total cost for each ID, number of F for each ID, number of M for each ID, First status of that ID based on date. Last status, Total cost for Failure.

My expected out put are shown below

```
   ID Ttl_cost  No_of_F No_of_M F_cost  First_Status    Last_status
0   1   2100     3        2     1850       F                F
1   2   1300     2        1     1100       M                F
2   3   1250     1        2     700        M                M
3   4   900      1        1     800        F                M
​
```

Comment: Your first dataframe does not even contain a column called ID nor Status. How do I tell whether each line is an F or M?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes and sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) per `ID` column for `sum`, [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html). Flatten `Multiindex` by `map` and `join`. Then use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for `sum` and `size` for counts, flatten again and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
df = df.sort_values('Date')

df2 = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Cost':['sum'], 'Status':['first','last']})
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)

df3 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Status', values='Cost', aggfunc=['sum','size'])
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'size':'No_of', 'sum':'Cost'})
df3.columns = df3.columns.map('_'.join)
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df4)
   ID  Cost_sum Status_first Status_last  Cost_F  Cost_M  No_of_F  No_of_M
0   1      2100            M           F    1850     250        3        2
1   2      1300            M           F    1100     200        2        1
2   3      1250            M           M     700     550        1        2
3   4       900            F           M     800     100        1        1
```